# Why where the aliens called Buggers in the book, but called the Formic in the movie?

Tags: names, adaptation-comparison, enders-game

I read *Ender's Game* about a year ago, and saw the movie shorty after. In the book the aliens are always addressed as "Buggers", however in the movie they are always called "The Formic". What was the reason for the change for the movie? I haven't read any of the other books yet, but in the other books do they start calling Buggers Formic too, or is that name specific to the movie?

It sounds like "Buggers" would be a slang term, while "Formic" might be a more scientific term. But, it seems out of place for the movie to change to only using a more scientific term especially when for children it would be more natural to say the slang term.

Comment: in the book bugger was the slang term, and formic was the "proper" name. id hazzard they just didn't want to use the word bugger in the movie in case it had any other meaning in current day to day usage. which it does >.< http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bugger it has a very bad connotation in English speaking countries out side of the US it appears.

Comment: Even in the UK there is some variation in how the word is regarded. There is a technical legal term but also a more innocent usage (especially up North).

Comment: @Himarm Ever heard of The Last Airbender? Everyone is refereed to as a _bender_ at some stage during the series, so it's not the word as such which was the issue. We have to remember Orson Scott Card was incredibly homophobic and so the word _Bugger_ has some unfortunate connotations in modern English.

Comment: @Fruitbat: if they'd been called "daft buggers" with the appropriate pronunciation on both words, I'd have been happy.

Comment: In my particular UK English variant, it wouldn't have been *offensive* so much as cringey. It'd be like calling the scary aliens "dumb-dumb-heads". It was bad enough in the books, but in a movie it would be harder to ignore.

Comment: @Blorgbeard But I could totally see a bunch of 10 year old kids calling scary aliens "dumb-dumb-heads" which is why it makes sense the kids would use the slang when talking about them. I would expect the adults to use the more scientific name.

Comment: Even that would be pretty awkward. Can you imagine watching that happen in the movie? I mean, *literally* having those kids repeatedly refer to the aliens as "dumb-dumb-heads", in conversation, not just as a one-off insult, in a blockbuster movie. That's about the same level of awkward/cringe as "buggers" would have elicited.

Comment: I've had a hunt around online and I can't see anything else to add to the answer below, especially in light of the quote from the film's director. Is there anything you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Daft In the UK The Last Airbender was called The Legend Of Aang, precisely because of the bender connotation. Admittedly they didn't remove it from the actual show itself, just changed the title, (thank goodness) but still.

Comment: @DavidS I saw the film in the UK and it was definitely still called The Last Airbender. I can’t find any reference to “The Legend of Aang” on IMDB, although the German title is listed as “Die Legende von Aang”.

Comment: @bornfromanegg It was the original (excellent) TV series that had the named changed. The (terrible) movie based on it kept the TLA name, presumably because the TV series had gained such strong positive PR and they wanted the brand association.

Answer (score 19):

According to this [CraveOnline interview](http://www.craveonline.co.uk/entertainment/film/interviews/643569-enders-game-exclusive-blu-ray-clip-gavin-hood-interview) with the film's director, Gavin Hood, the decision to remove the offending word from the screenplay was taken by Card himself, after he supposedly had a change of heart regarding the possible upset that his choice of name could cause:

> **Q.** *Was it your decision to never refer to the Formics as “Buggers” in the movie?*
>
> **A.** *It was actually a request from Orson Scott Card in his conversation with Gigi Pritzker early on if you can believe that. I
>   think he recognized that the term might mean something that he didn’t
>   realize, that’s what he said, it meant when he wrote the book in
>   1985.*

Obviously by the point that the film was made, the name had been retconned out of the prequels and sequels, leading to the odd situation that chronologically the people of Earth start referring to them as Buggers, then stop abruptly.

Comment: [snip] - If you wish to discuss the author's religion or personal opinions, [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) is the place to do it.

Comment: All editions of the Ender's Game book have still used the term Bugger. Card will likely change it when he makes the revised edition he keeps on talking about, but that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: There's a specific passage in Ender's Shadow, in the middle of chapter 2; "Or should I say Formics, since they're now saying Buggers is a bad word in English, even though I.F. Common is not English..." So, the author has been trying to change it since at least 2000.

But I'm not sure Retcon is the right word, as it suggest removing and pretending it was never there in the first place.

Comment: @Jontia - Rumours abound that in the new edition of Ender's Game (fully revised to fit all the previous retcons) the term will be disposed of entirely.

Comment: Very interesting. I shall have to see if I can grab a library copy when the new edition comes out. Thanks for the additional details.

Comment: @Jontia - Card has been promising it for over ten years by now. If it ever does come out it likely won't be any time soon. (Last word on the matter was that it's being delayed until after Formic Wars is finished.) If you want to see what it'll be like just listen up Ender's Game Alive.

Comment: I think you mean: "leading to the odd situation that chronologically the people of Earth start referring to them as Buggers, then stop abruptly, *and then start again a few thousand years later*." (The last three chronological books were all published before Card decided to stop calling them buggers.)

Answer (score 6):

I read somewhere that "Formic" was used to draw a distinction between them and the alien bugs in the Starship Troopers movies. I don't recall where I originally read that but I did find this comment by O.S.C. on a message board
http://www.hatrack.com/cgi-bin/ubbmain/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=1;t=002830;p=1

> Until the movie Starship Troopers came out, I thought of the buggers
>   as vaguely insectoid, which meant I thought of smooth-carapaced
>   creatures with six limbs and multi-faceted eyes.
>
> Starship Troopers cured THAT idea. The last think I want is for anyone
>   to look at Ender's Game and think of that movie. So not only did we
>   change the name, for film purposes, from Buggers to Formics, but also
>   we reconceived the buggers as being warm-blooded and furry. No smooth
>   shell.
>
> And we were free to do this precisely because I had not described them
>   beyond "insectoid." Which they still are, being wasp-waisted and
>   six-limbed.

Comment: I could see that being a possibility, do you have any evidence to back up that claim?

Comment: edited above to add a reference

Comment: @matt1618 - Great find. You have my +1

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formics) covers this rather succinctly:

> The term "Formic" is derived from formica, the Latin word for ant;
>   whereas "bugger" is a pejorative used by humans; yet it was not until
>   1999's Ender's Shadow that the term 'Formic' was first used,
>   interchangeably with 'Bugger'. Later books used 'Formic' almost
>   exclusively, as the more 'scientific' term.... The feature film
>   adaptation of Ender's Game uses "Formics" exclusively.

So, it's a mix in the books, and the movie picked one.  One might suppose that using a pejorative sounding term like "bugger" would make movie execs nervous...

Comment: yeah, in the US, 'bugger' isn't really a bad word, but for foreign English speaking markets it is a quite bad.

Comment: I'm English and I don't see myself as being 'foreign'(!).  In British English 'Bugger!" is a swearword.  A bugger is someone who performs anal sex or is being disparaged. The only benign meaning of 'bugger' in UK English would be "a poor bugger", i.e. someone who deserves sympathy. Even this version should be used cautiously.

Comment: In Australian English bugger is a pretty soft curse actually about on the level of "oops". [This ad features *only* the word bugger and was played in prime-time Australian TV.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbBx4Ql6Umo)